# Ternary operator in a foreach syntax

Tags: java, collections, foreach, ternary-operator

I have two `String` collections: `String... columns` - which is just a simple array and a `KeySet<String>` from a map.

```
for(String it : columns) // works
for(String it : FIELDS.keySet()) // works
for(String it : ((columns.length > 0) ? columns : FIELDS.keySet())) // doesn't.
```

> Foreach not applicable to type Object.

Why is that?

Comment: Try `for(String it : columns.length > 0 ? Arrays.asList(columns) : FIELDS.keySet())` this will mean the common type is `Iterable<String>`

Answer (score 5):

When you use two expressions in a ternary as two alternatives, Java needs to decide what's their common type, in order to decide the type of the expression.

Since `columns` is `String[]`, and `FIELDS.keySet()` is `Set<String>`, the best common type is `java.lang.Object`. Each individual type supports iteration, but the common base type does not. That's why you get an error.

You can fix this by converting `columns` to a `Set<String>`, or by converting `FIELDS.keySet()` to `String[]`:

```
Set<String> keySet = FIELDS.keySet();
String[] keyArray = keySet.toArray(new String[keySet.size()])
for(String it : ((columns.length > 0) ? columns : keyArray)) {
    ...
}
```

> (from the comment) Conversion is not worth in my case. Simple `if for(x) else for(y)` will fit better cause it's a one-line loop and less consuming than the copy.

Another reason this is more efficient is that Java compiler is able to generate more efficient code. As [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) noted [in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42747427/ternary-operator-in-a-foreach-syntax/42747455?noredirect=1#comment72611845_42747455) below,

> [Java] compiler has to emit different code for them, depending on whether it's dealing with an array or an `Iterable`

Your approach with two `foreach` lets the compiler pick an enhanced loop that better fits the collection type, rather than shoehorning both collections into an object of the same type.

Comment: Conversion is not worth in my case. Simple `if for(x) else for(y)` will fit better cause it's a one-line loop and less consuming than the copy. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @Spectre: It's also worth noting that there are really effectively two [enhanced `for` statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) in Java, not just one. One of them loops through arrays; the other loops through `Iterable`s. The compiler has to emit *different* code for them, depending on whether it's dealing with an array or an `Iterable`.

Comment: Alternatively, use `columns.length > 0 ? Arrays.asList(columns) : FIELDS.keySet()`.

Comment: As an aside, stream operations make all of this a lot easier to formulate.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the two parts of a ternary operator must share the same common type in order for them to qualify for the for-each construct.  The for-each construct expects either `Object[]` or `Iterable`.

In your case however one is an `array`, and the other is a `Set`.  The closest mutual parent these two types have is `Object` and so that becomes the final type of the ternary expression.

Comment: They don't need to be exactly the same type, but they both must be assignable to either `Object[]` or `Iterable`.